# How to create wavy text animation?

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 project to show scrolling text. My code is as follows :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'This is right scrolling text ';
  Timer1.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
begin
  S := Label1.Caption;
  S := S[Length(S)] + Copy(S, 1, Length(S) - 1);
  Label1.Caption := S;
end;

end.
```

Using the following code the text scrolls perfectly in 2d along to Y axis.

**How to scroll text in `Sinusoidal Wave` ?**

[image: Sample Wavy Text]

Comment: Can you define precisely what you are looking for. Text horizontal? Or text angled at sinusoid tangent. And why do you have that space in the string still. You don't need it!

Comment: Actually I need that some text will move from left to right in waves i.e. wavy text. 100%! I need it.

Comment: Easiest way is obviously drawing the text on a Canvas using an algorithm. Do some research on that and then come back and post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Text
horizontal? Or text angled at sinusoid tangent. I ask again.

Comment: I have just added the sample image.

Comment: I can imagine how your next question will look like. You'll take the code from the answer to this question telling you need a revolving text around a sphere :-)

Comment: No.. No...Don't think in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Angus Johnson's excellent [GR32_Text](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/gr32_lines.php) extension to the fine graphics32 library appears to do what you need. The demos that you can download from the link above show just the effect you are asking for. All that remains is for you to animate the text in a paint box or similar control.